# Private Properties in Controllers

Tags: angularjs

As my controllers become more complicated, i have properties that should not be mofified. What is the best practice for creating private properties on controllers which can only be accessed by mutators?

A contrived example:

```
.controller('ProjectManagerController', function($scope){
    $scope.formVisible = false;

    $scope.showForm = function(){
        $scope.formVisible = true;
    }
 })
```

Is it ok to indicate $scope.formVisible is private by convention (a la pythons leading underscore)?
Should i use some sort of closure?

Comment: if its private, why are you keeping it on $scope??

Comment: Aha! That's what i was missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like this approach.

```
.controller('ProjectManagerController', function($scope){
var formVisible = false;

$scope.showForm = function(value){
    if(value === undefined){
        return formVisible;
    }
    formVisible = value;
}
})
```

Usage:

```
.showForm() //get value
.showForm(true/false); //to update value
```

Comment: try the "controller as ctrl" Syntax so you don't need the $scope any more in the Controller and all Properties you want to use in the view are defined with "this.showForm = true" and all other variables you can't access in the View